# How does curl relate to rotation?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, curl

The operation mathematically means $$(\nabla \times \vec A)\cdot\hat n  = \lim_{\Delta S\to\ 0} \frac{\oint\vec A\cdot\ d\vec l }{\left | \Delta S \right |}$$ and the proof of this is quite logical. 
 In textbooks, I have found that they relate *curl to rotation*. 
 But how does the above mathematical treatment show this relation?

Any mathematical help is welcome.

Comment: @user36790 I have posted the question on MathSE here.

Comment: The curl should be a vector, not a scalar.

Comment: @littleO Can you please edit the equation suitably? I found this equation in a textbook of mine.

Comment: You could state it as $(\nabla \times \vec A)\cdot n = \lim_{\Delta S \to 0} \frac{\oint \vec A \cdot d \vec \ell}{| \Delta S |}$, where $\Delta S$ is a planar oriented surface and with unit normal vector $n$, and $| \Delta S|$ is the area of $\Delta S$.  Here $\oint \vec A \cdot d \vec \ell$ is the line integral of $\vec A$ around the boundary of $\Delta S$.  Note that to avoid difficulties in defining this limit, a rigorous approach usually defines $\nabla \times A$ using the standard formula for the curl.

Comment: It might be helpful to imagine what happens if $\vec A $ describes a fluid that's flowing in circles, in planes orthogonal to $\vec n $. This kind of flow makes the quantity on the right very large.

Comment: Try to compute the curl of the vector field $(-\sin(t),\cos(t),0)$ (which would describe the direction of a particle moving around a circle of radius $1$). Also try to compute the curl of the vector field $(x,y,0)$ (which would describe the direction of a particle moving directly away from the origin).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\bf{C}$ be any vector-field. Let there be a closed-curve $\Gamma$. Take the line-integral of $\bf C$ around this complete loop that is, take the tangential-component of the field at any point on the curve & take dot-product of $\mathbf{C}_\text{tangential}\cdot d\mathbf{s}$ & integrate over the whole loop. This is circulation : $$\text{Circulation}_{\Gamma}=\int_{\Gamma} \mathbf{ C} \cdot d\mathbf{s}.$$

[image: circulation]

Now make partitions on $C$ with an intermediary-bridge, say $B$; this then will make two loops viz; $\Gamma_1 \;\&\; \Gamma_2.$ Now circulation over the whole loop is just line-integral around each sub-loop that is, $$\text{Circulation}_{\Gamma} \\= \text{Circulation}_{\Gamma_1} + \text{Circulation}_{\Gamma_2}\\= (\text{Circulation}_{\Gamma_a} + \text{Circulation}_{\Gamma_{ab}}) + (\text{Circulation}_{\Gamma_b} -\text{Circulation}_{\Gamma_{ab}})\\ =\text{Circulation}_{\Gamma_{a}} +  \text{Circulation}_{\Gamma_{b}}.$$

[image: division of loop]

Break into still further smaller loops as $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2,\Gamma_3 \ldots \Gamma_N.$

[image: further division of the loop]

Circulation over the whole-loop $$\int_{\Gamma} \mathbf{C}\cdot d\mathbf{s}= \sum_{i=1}^N\int_{\Gamma_i} \mathbf{C}\cdot d\mathbf{s}_i.$$

Now we want to get the infinitesimal-circulation characteristic to a certain coordinate. We then make $N\to \infty;$ however each integral that is $\int_{\Gamma_i} \mathbf{C}\cdot d\mathbf{s}_i \to 0$ as $N\to \infty.$ So, in order to get the finite characteristic which is associated with circulation locally to a point, we divide each integral by the area enclosed by each sub-loop. That is, take the *ratio of circulation to loop area*$$\frac{\text{Circulation}_{\Gamma_i}}{a_i}.$$ This is our local-property that is the infinitesimal circulation of the vector-field at a certain point (around it) is given by $$\lim_{a_i\to 0} \frac{\int_{\Gamma_i} \mathbf{C}\cdot d\mathbf{s}_i}{a_i}.$$

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with rotations, as was asked by the OP.

Comment: @Alex M.: He wanted to know how circulation is related to the formula; I deduced it using argument that relates how circulation is related to the formula; lf you don't like then there is an answer-box, I think....

Comment: Dear Aniket, it is my duty to ask whether my answer helped you or not. Just comment on what are your problems that still persist so that I may help.

Comment: @user36790 Your answer is quite good and self-explanatory. I have understood it. Only one thing: In the fist paragraph, you first take dot product of $F_{tangential}⋅ds$ but then you write  $\tau = F⋅ds$. So is it $F_{tangential}$ or just $F$?

Comment: @user36790 sorry, the pictures can not be viewed. Can you reload them again?

Comment: What is the problem? I'm not getting it; I am seeing the pics in my laptop; sorry: are you saying the links are broken? I will then fix them. Regarding $\bf{F}_\text{tangential},$ you can either of the dot-products; they will yield the same result as there are no projections of $d\bf{s}$ perpendicularly.

Comment: @Aniket: Are you seeing the pics now? Sorry, I didn't pay heed to your request earlier as I was clearly seeing the pics. However, the files were not supported in SE. I've converted them to `jpg`; hope you can see them now.

Comment: @user36790 yup now the pics are crystal clear.

Answer (score 3):

**First a small disclaimer** as the rotation may not be rotation in the same sense as the question-maker intends, but anyways. Please tell me if I misunderstand the question and I can remove it.

A rotation $\phi$ radians can be described as $\left[\begin{array}{rr}
a&-b\\b&a\end{array}\right], {a = \cos(\phi), b = \sin(\phi)}$, and an infinitesimal rotation in vector analysis is $$\nabla \times {\bf v} = \frac{\partial {\bf v}_x}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial {\bf v}_y}{\partial x}$$ So how do these relate to each other, or more interestingly how does $\phi$ relate to the cross product above.

An interesting thing is that the matrix operator above is in fact how the vector *changes*, not how it *moves* i.e. the additive part. To get the additive part, we need to take **I minus the rotated vector**, i.e. the change vector.

We need some discrete filters to measure the rotation, and here are some basic traditional *Sobel* filters. These are linear filters which are applied on a discretization of a function, usually on a regular cartesian grid. In mathematical terms we perform a discrete *convolution* with the filters

$$D_x = \left[\begin{array}{rr}
1&0&-1\\2&0&-2\\1&0&-1\end{array}\right] \hspace{1cm} D_y = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1&2&1\\0&0&0\\-1&-2&-1\end{array}\right]$$

This convolution is defined as $$F(i,j) = \sum_{k,l \in \{0,1,2,3\}} I(i+k,j+l)D_x(3-k,3-l)$$
and produces the *filter response* $F$. You can read more about [linear filtering (discrete convolution)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)  and [Sobel filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) in particular.

[image]
Local displacement vector field. Each vector points out from the middle with the difference in coordinates.

[image]

After applying the rotation described above for $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Each vector contains it's own displacement compared to before rotation.

[image]

Applying the curl filters according to curl formula and fitting to a $sin$ curve shows that we can do curl on a proper rotation field and estimate phi., the scale 16 (sin maximum) can be adjusted by normalizing the discrete filters accordingly.

Comment: Please complete the solution as soon as possible.

Comment: Oh yes sorry. I forgot about it, working on some illustrations now.

Comment: Fixed some embarrasing bugs in my code. This should make more sense. Largest "rotation" for $\pm$ $\pi / 4$ and there is a sign change for half a revolution, as we know should be the case for curl. Negative or positive $\hat {\bf z}$ deciding counter clockwise or clockwise rotation.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote?

Comment: Me in a dilemma too. Someone has downvoted my question and both the answers. I don't why.

Comment: I don't know; even I got the downvote; your answer, I thought, was quite satisfactory...

Comment: I am undoing the downvote; I don't think it deserves this at all.

Comment: @mathreadler Don't know much about Sobel filters. So couldn't understand what you tried to portray through the diagrams. Can you explain in a bit simple language?

Comment: Ok great. I added some details about linear filtering (discrete convolution) to explain the filtering.

Comment: Basically the convolution with Sobel filters creates a discrete approximation of a derivative with respect to $x$ and to $y$ on a cartesian grid. So we assume we have measured the vector field at discrete points on a cartesian grid and then the filtering performs approximations to the derivatives used in the curl operator.